# Clementine Dark-Light Icons in Unity tray

Tags: unity, 13.04, icons, clementine

Do not matter which icon set I use, Ubuntu-Mono-Light or Ubuntu-Mono-Dark, the Clementine tray icon does not change. I have found that in both themes there is a icon called "clementine-panel-grey.png" but it is not used.

Any ideas?

Comment: **This comment is completely offtopic**, [fs-icons](http://www.noobslab.com/2013/04/fs-icons-for-ubuntu-130412101204linux.html) are the best icons I have ever install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not why but after play with themes and icons finally the Clementine's icon is provided by Ubuntu-mono-light

:-S